# AutomationProperty Automation ID for Ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I have a ellipse that I'm trying to automatically hover over however I can't seem to find the property using a tool like FlaUIInspect. I suspect it's cause Ellipse doesn't expose the automation peer or something like that?

Here's a simple version of my Ellipse:

```
<Ellipse AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Ellipse">
    <Ellipse.ToolTip>
        ...
    </Ellipse.ToolTip>
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        ...                                        
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

If it is an automation peer thing, how would I go about implementing that?

Comment: That's accurate, it is not the kind of UI object that automation programs know about.

Comment: @HansPassant how would I get the automation program to know about it?